# Query to find all empty tables 

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

Considering that I have a Schema named SBST

I want to find all empty tables list in this SBST Schema. Is there any PL/SQL procedure to find that. I found few. But those were using user tables where I was not able specify the Schema name SBST.

I was using this

```
select table_name from dba_tables where owner ='SBST'
having count(*)=0  group by table_name
```

What's wrong in the above query?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Similar to @shareef's answer, but using [dynamic SQL](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14072_01/appdev.112/e10472/dynamic.htm) to avoid having to create the temporary `.sql` file. You'll need [`dbms_output`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25788/d_output.htm) to be visible, e.g. with [`set serveroutput on`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve040.htm#sthref2166) in SQL*Plus - don't know about Toad.

```
declare
    cursor c(p_schema varchar2) is
        select 'select ''' || table_name || ''' from ' ||
            p_schema ||'.' || table_name || ' where rownum < 2 ' ||
            ' having count(*) = 0' as query
        from all_tables
        where owner = p_schema
        order by table_name;
    l_table all_tables.table_name%TYPE;
begin
    for r in c('SBST') loop
        begin
            execute immediate r.query into l_table;
        exception
            when no_data_found then continue;
        end;

        dbms_output.put_line(l_table);
    end loop;
end;
/
```

Using `all_tables` seems more useful than `dba_tables` here so you know you can select from the tables it lists. I've also included the schema in the `from` clause in case there other users have tables with the same name, and so you can still see it if you're connected as a different user - possibly avoiding synonym issues too.

---

Specifically what's wrong with your query... you've got the `having` and `group by` clauses the wrong way around; but it will always return no data anyway because if SBST has any tables then `count (*) from dba_tables` must be non-zero, so the `having` always matches; and if it doesn't then, well, there's no data anyway so there's nothing for the `having` to match against. You're counting how many tables there are, not how many rows are in each table.

Comment: `having` clause is not necessary. `SELECT 1 FROM owner.table WHERE rownum < 2` woud be enough to determine whether there is at least 1 row in the table.

Comment: @ipip - yes, and that's slightly faster on my data, which includes some reasonably big tables; but gives you tables that do have data, and the OP wants those that don't.

Comment: No, I'm talking rubbish; it's a lot faster if I run it on the DB that does actually have significant data, as you'd expect. But it does list tables with data; combining both clauses seems to do the trick though. Thanks.

Comment: Taht's OK, I just wanted to point out the way, how to find an empty table. I often find myself doing the same :-)

Comment: @peter:That helped a lot Alex

Answer (score 7):

You can fire below query to find the list of tables haveing no data

```
select * from ALL_TABLES 
where owner ='SBST'
AND NUM_ROWS = 0;
```

Comment: not working for me, apparently it's an estimate ; https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/76409/num-rows-in-dba-tables-not-reflecting-the-real-number-of-rows-in-tables-oracle-9

Answer (score 4):

the straight forward answer is

```
select 'select ''' || table_name || ''' from ' || table_name || ' 
    having count(*) = 0;' from dba_tables where owner='SBST';
```

**EXPLANATION**

You can run this... it will just output the table names of those having no rows:
assuming you use sqlplus but i used toad to test it 
and it worked very well 
    set echo off heading off feedback off lines 100 pages 0;

```
spool tmp.sql
select 'select ''' || table_name || ''' from ' || table_name || ' 
having count(*) = 0;' from user_tables where owner='SBST';
spool off;

@tmp.sql
```

If you open the "tmp.sql" file, you'll see for all tables....

```
select 'PERSONS' from PERSONS having count(*) = 0;
select 'DEPARTMENT' from DEPARTMENT having count(*)=0;
```

in your case you want a schema and schema is a user right the above code if you connect with the user **SBST** but if you connect with other then you have to use **DBA_TABLES** and assign **owner** attribute to **SBST**

> **USER_TABLES** is tables which you own **ALL_TABLES** is tables which own,
>   and tables owner by other users, which you have been granted excplicit
>   access to **DBA_TABLES** is all tables in the database

like this

```
set echo off heading off feedback off lines 100 pages 0;

spool tmp.sql
select 'select ''' || table_name || ''' from ' || table_name || ' 
having count(*) = 0;' from dba_tables where owner='SBST';
spool off;

@tmp.sql
```

> All three are views of the underlying SYS tables,  but the USER_ and
>   ALL_ views joing in your username/security info to limit the results

[image: my result image upload]

**SUMMARY **

PLEASE JUST RUN THIS QUERY

```
select 'select ''' || table_name || ''' from ' || table_name || ' 
    having count(*) = 0;' from dba_tables where owner='SBST';
```

Comment: @peter Is there any way to specify SBST directly in the query.I am executing in Toad.Datswhy

Comment: i added it above in the edit `select 'select ''' || table_name || ''' from ' || table_name || ' 
having count(*) = 0;' from dba_tables where owner='SBST';
`

Comment: @peter:The above prints the tablename along with having count.This means i want to copy all the result in a file and execute this.Is there any query as such?

Comment: @peter just run this <br>`select 'select ''' || table_name || ''' from ' || table_name || ' 
    having count(*) = 0;' from dba_tables where owner='SBST';
`

Answer (score 2):

If table stats are up to date then you could use:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME
FROM ALL_TAB_STATISTICS
WHERE (OWNER = 'ME')
  AND (NUM_ROWS = 0);
```